# Python does not write data to disk

Tags: python, file-io, cluster-computing, flush

I am trying to establish a python script which runs on a scientific cluster.

It split an input file into chunks submit them one to the cluster, sort and evaluate the ouput and submit the next chunk.

However, I have a strange problem.

I create the input file for the subprocess directly before the process. However, it never worked and showed me an "No data to process" error.

I finally run this fragment:

```
tmp = open ("individual_list.txt","w")
for line in working:
    tmp.write (line)
tmp.close
tmp.flush
os.fsync
time.sleep(60)
command=["srun"]
command.append ("--cpus-per-task=1")
command.append ("--chdir="+cwd)
command.append ("-o")
command.append (uniqueID+"#"+str(loop)+"_mut.out")
command.append (EXEC)
#command=[EXEC]
command.append ("-runfile")
command.append (CMD1)
out= open (uniqueID+"#"+str(loop)+"_mut.out","w")
p1=subprocess.Popen (command, cwd=cwd)
p1.wait()
out.close
```

You probably noticed that I already went paranoid with buffered output. But still during the minute of waiting, the file individual_list.txt is created in the filesystem but empty.
It only gets filled after the subprocess finished.
Is this a python problm or do I have to ask our cluster admins for help?

Best,
Jan

Comment: unrelated: you could use string formatting: `outputfile = "{id}#{n}_mut.out".format(id=uniqueId, n=loop)`

Comment: you could write it as: `with open("individual_list.txt","w") as file: file.writelines(working)` It closes (and flushes) the file automatically. You don't need `os.fsync(); time.sleep(60)`.

Comment: `subprocess.Popen(..).wait()` is equivalent to `subprocess.call(..)`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thanks for the tipps. The wait was only for debugging and the flush and fsync only because of bug hunting. All three commands are now gone! I use .Popen for defining the cwd... I thought that is not possible with .call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not calling the `close` and `flush` methods.  You need to place `()` after them to do this:

```
tmp.close()
tmp.flush()
etc.
```

Otherwise, you just have references to those methods.  Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> def foo():
...     return 'hi'
...
>>> foo
<function foo at 0x020B2540>
>>> foo()
'hi'
>>>
```

Comment: Your are totaly right, I outed myself as python noob :-( However, thanks a lot you ended a long time of frustration!